# Processing CSV file without double quotes

Tags: python, perl, shell, csv, delimiter

In other words, I am looking for a way to ignore ", " in one of the fields.

The field should be treated as one single field even though it contains a comma.

Example:

```
Round,Winner,place,prize
1,xyz,1,$4,500
```

If I read this with dict reader `$4,500` is printed as `$4` because `500` is considered to be another field., This makes sense as I am reading the file as comma delimited, so I can't really complain but try to figure out a work around.

```python
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
```

My source is not wrapped in double quotes so I can't ignore by including a quote string.

Is there any other way to handle this scenario? Probably something like define these dollar fields and make it ignore commas for that field? Or try to inserrt quotes around this field?

If not Python, could shell script or Perl be used to do it?

Comment: Your input data is broken, and you'll only be able to get band-aid solutions such as "ignore first comma after dollar sign" - is that good enough?

Comment: Luckily the `prize` column is last, otherwise this would be even more of a pain in the ass (use the header to keep track of the number, `m`, of columns, take the columns up to the dollar sign, take columns from the right until you get `m-1` of them, then glom the remaining stuff in the middle to form the `prize` field...blech)

Comment: @ Benjamin W - Yea, at this point I have to assume that I am going to get a broken data if not always but sometimes it may be. So bandage would be go to choice right now.

Comment: @JackManey ... Let me give it a try. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps pre-process the data to wrap all money in quotes, then process normally

```
$line =~ s/( \$\d+ (?:,\d{3})* (?:\.\d{2})? )/"$1"/gx;
```

The pattern matches digits following a `$`, optionally followed by any multiples of `,nnn` and/or by one `.nn`. It also wraps `$4.22` as well as `$100`, which I consider good for consistency. Restrict what gets matched if needed, for example to `(\$\d{1,3},\d{3})`. With fractional cents remove `{2}`. This doesn't cover all possible edge/broken cases.

The `/g` modifier makes it replace all such in the line and `/x` allows spaces for readibilty.

You can do it as a one-liner

```
perl -pe 's/(\$\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?)/"$1"/g' input.csv  > changed.csv
```

Add `-i` switch to overwrite input ("*in-place*"), or `-i.bak` to also keep backup.

---

If you anticipate further need for tweaks, or to document this better, put it in a script

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = '...';
my $fout = '...';

open my $fh,     '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";
open my $fh_out, '>', $fout or die "Can't open $fout for writing: $!";

while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    $line =~ s/( \$\d+ (?:,\d{3})* (?:\.\d{2})? )/"$1"/gx;
    print fh_out $line;
}

close $fh;
close $fh_out;
```

Comment: zdim: You mentioned restrictions: Since we don't know anything about the values occuring in other fields, a trailing $, immediately followed by a comma would match too! So a minimal restriction of /(\$\d[\d,]+)/ maybe, or given the case of currency to reformat: /(\$\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)/ ?

Comment: @SREagle, I applied a fix.

Comment: ikegami: What about 'bling$$$,100,' =~ /(\$[\d,]*\d)/ ? Wouldn't that still match?

Comment: It's a heuristic, so one can always come up with a case where something will be interpreted as a price when it shouldn't. The key is finding a solution that works for the data that will actually be encountered. But yeah, `\$\d+(?:,\d{3})*` is better than `\$[\d,]*\d`, both because it's more restrictive, and because it performs less backtracking.

Comment: @ikegami  Thank you very much for fixes. I am going to add now a note on the fractional amounts as well, which I completely forgot about

Comment: I tend to be pedantic in these cases, having overlooked - and in turn corrupted - far to many data that needed repair that way. Better save than sorry! (And being reminded of overlooking just seconds ago by zdim's additional case :( )

Comment: @SREagle, I was just keeping the change minimal at first since it wasn't my answer.

Comment: @SREagle Thank you for comments. I think that it's easy to imagine messed-up data that will throw if off here but I'd first consider likely (and good) data.

Comment: @zdim Thanks . It worked perfectly. Something I was expecting. Would the regex in a similar way for address field ? I know we are referencing $ to isolate the amount field but I am wondering how this may work for address or any other field for that matter. I think that is too much to think.. I am trying to correct it at source level and have this as integrity check for amount fields. Thanks Again.

Comment: @jb04 Unless there's a set format for the address, it would be next to impossible to accurately parse. Ultimately, you're trying to solve a non-technical problem (your data provider is giving you broken data) with a technical solution, which is never a recipe for success.

Comment: @jb04 If you mean whether a regex in general can be used for it ... well, yes in principle, but addresses can come in _many_ forms and there is not even the magical `$`.  It just gets harder and harder with every next variation.  If you have a strictly set format of the address, then it's easy ... if there can be no errors. Once you look for possible glitches in data it gets really tricky quick.

Comment: @zdim My Bad, I was about to say _"it may not work for address field"_ 

Yes, I agree with you that it is harder to expand regex to counter the broken data. It is best to correct them at source or to wrap them within double quotes. I will accept yours as Answers. Thanks

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Agreed.

Answer (score 1):

If the extra `,` is always going to be a part of the last field when it exists, you could use a Bash read loop for it:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=, read -r f1 f2 f3 f4; do
   # f4 => has everything after f3, including extra commas as in $4,500
   # do your processing
   printf "f1=[$f1] f2=[$f2] f3=$[f3] f4=[$f4]\n"
done < input.txt
```

Input:

```
1,xyz,1,$4,500
2,abc,3,$400
```

Output:

```
f1=[1] f2=[xyz] f3=1 f4=[$4,500]
f1=[2] f2=[abc] f3=3 f4=[$400]
```

Comment: The problem is I might be reading many csv files and each of them would have a different layout or no of fields. So it could be difficult to say if it always be at the end and how many fields I am anticipating in the file. I have to write a dynamic way to define no of fields plus I am not sure if any performance bottlenecks be present when working on large datasets